# How to print a html page received from the server?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, node.js

I am attempting to print a HTML page which I have generated using `Node.js` at my server. I have brought the page to client side as a response to an AJAX request and have it in a `javascript` variable.

`var resp_json = printRequest.getResponseJson();`

Now I am trying to **print** the rendered HTML page (i.e. without the tags) not the DOM object that would be sent.

I read about `window.print()` but it only prints the current page in the browser. Can anyone suggest me a way to approach.

Also, is generating an HTML page at the node is the right approach or should be it any other kind of document. The page is supposed to be dynamically generated at the node and the end result should be a printed document.
Thanx in advance!!

P.S. I am using closure library, don't ask why, that was already decided for me.

P.P.S. I am fairly new to `javascript` and `node.js` so don't be afraid to give lengthy lectures, I am all ears!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Without pop-up**

```
function printHTMLString(htmlString) {
     var originalDocument = document.body.innerHTML;    
     document.body.innerHTML = htmlString;    
     window.print();   
     document.body.innerHTML = originalDocument;
}
```

**With pop-up**

```
var popupWIndow = window.open('','','width=200,height=100');    
popupWIndow.document.write(jsonResponse);    
popupWindow.window.print();
```

if for some reason it doesn't work, add following line before print()

```
popupWindow.window.location.reload();
```

Also you need to convert json object to string before printing

```
JSON.stringify(jsonObject)
```

but for all of this to work, browser has to be able to read it as an HTML page so it can render it. JSON objects won't work.

Comment: It didn't worked. Firstly, I had to allow pop-ups on my browser which is a big no-no. Secondly, it opened a pop-up after I allowed it and printed my page in it but the print prompt didn't came on.

Comment: `ReferenceError: popupWindow is not defined`

Comment: Check your variable name. I have added a solution without pop-up too. Try if it works for you.

Comment: The without pop-up method worked beautifully only with a slight hitch. The original page was displayed back only after the user had press OK on the print prompt, until then the to-be-printed html document was shown.

Comment: Yes. Sorry about that. An elegant solution would be to open a hidden `iframe` with htmlString and then print it. Your current page will not be affected at all. Please accept as answer if it helped.

Comment: Glad I could help. Do think about my earlier comment on using hidden `iframe` as an elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

With it you can render a pdf from whatever page wether directly from url or by file. It will render the page as pdf you could then print the entire pdf.

nb : you can print one page or concatenate multiple pages.

Comment: @Amo The rendering should be performed at server side. If I do this I would have to send a pdf file to the client, where can I go from there?

Comment: you can execute wkhtmltopdf server side it's what I do.

Comment: ok suppose I did that, how would I print a pdf file at the client-side? How to open the print prompt for the file through javascript?

Comment: Print using server side scripting or application that you would call from your web page using a form or a get or whatever client - server form of communication. You can then send the file to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Common practice is to open a new browser window with the content you want to print, then invoke window.print()

Comment: That is an option but it would first display the page before printing it, which I am trying to avoid. If worse comes to worst, this is the way I have decided to go.

Answer (score 0):

you can create an iframe, add your html page to `iframe.src` and then call print:

```
window.frames[yourIframeName].focus();
window.frames[yourIframeName].print();
```